# What flavor of RegEx does Orbeon use?

Tags: regex, orbeon, xforms, formbuilder

I'm trying to include a regular impression in orbeon Form Builder to prevent inputs with ' and ". The problem I'm facing is that every combination of RegEx expression I attempt fails the validation in some way. Not when the focus changes, but when the form is submitted.

The regex: `[^'"]{0,512} /m`

Should allow all strings up to and including 512 characters that does not include the aforementioned `'` and `"`. including strings with carriage return.

In Orbeon in the "formulars" field: `matches(.,"^[^''""]{0,512}$","m")`

The problem is that Orbeon validates the expression `[^''""]` differently depending upon if the `'` and `"` are entered before or after a carriage return in the string.

Example:

This will fail (i.e. the expression is successfully validated):

```
Hi my dog's collar is blue
this is because it is my favorite colour.
```

This will pass (i.e. the expression fails to work):

```
Hi
my dog's collar is blue
this is because it is my favorite colour.
```

I have two questions:

1. Why does the validation differ depending upon the location of the `"` and `'`?
2. What expression would make the validation work as intended?

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: Looks like it's only considering the first line of the input.  What happens if you get rid of the `"m"` flag?

Comment: To answer the question in the title: the flavor is the one from [XQuery 1.0 and XPath 2.0 Functions and Operators (Second Edition)](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#regex-syntax).

Comment: Whatever flavor it is, in multiline mode the anchors (`^` and `$`) are supposed to match at line boundaries, which is not what you want.  In fact, *both* of your inputs should match, since each contains at least one line with no `"` or `'` in it.  There appears to be a bug somewhere, but you should be able to solve your problem by dropping the `"m"` flag.